# JavaScript prototypal inheritance workaround

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

Here is an example:

```
var Box = function() {
    this.id = generateUniqueId();
};
Box.prototype = {
    add:function(parent) {
        parent.appendChild(this.elm);
    }
};

var NewBox = function() {
    this.newThing = true;
};
NewBox.prototype = new Box();
NewBox.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.elm.parentNode.removeChild(this.elm);
};

var a = new NewBox();
var b = new NewBox();
alert(a.id); // alerts 0
alert(b.id); // also alerts 0! :@
```

I would like to have a and b (basically each time I create a `NewBox`) have their own `id`. I understand that `NewBox` is using prototypal inheritance and is thus inheriting from a single instance of the generated `id` that it gets from `Box`, but I would like it so that each `NewBox` gets its own `id` without having to explicitly say that inside the `NewBox` constructor.

Maybe it's impossible or I'm doing something really wrong, so please help!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe it's impossible or I'm doing something really wrong, so please help!

You're doing something wrong.

If you want instance-specific values, initialize them in the constructor, not the prototype.

Comment: that was the answer i figured, but i was hoping thered be some sweet javascript trick around it. thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In your example, the `Box` constructor gets executed only when you set the `NewBox.prototype` object.

You could workaround this by calling the `Box` constructor function inside `NewBox` with the [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method, to set the `this` value and forward all the argument values, for example:

```
//..
var NewBox = function() {
    Box.apply(this, arguments);
    this.newThing = true;
};
//..

var a = new NewBox();
var b = new NewBox();

// assuming your `generateUniqueId` function
// increments a number

alert(a.id); // will alert 1
alert(b.id); // will alert 2
```

Now, each time the `NewBox` constructor is called to create a new object instance (`new NewBox();`), it will call the `Box` function to apply all its logic on it. This will help you to avoid repeating the logic of the parent constructor over and over.

The `apply`, is used call the "parent" constructor function setting the `this` value to the object instance that is being created by the `NewBox` constructor and we pass all arguments provided to this function.

Your example also shows a common problem, when you express inheritance relationship through `NewBox.prototype = new Box();` the `Box` constructor gets called and it has side effects, this new object will be initialized and your `generateUniqueId` function will be executed for the first time, if you want to avoid that, you need to either use a temp constructor, just to make a new object that inherits from `Box.prototype`, or use the new ECMAScript 5 `Object.create` method for the same purpose, for example:

```
function inherit(o) {
  function Tmp() {}
  Tmp.prototype = o;
  return new Tmp();
}

//.....
NewBox.prototype = inherit(Box.prototype);
```

Or:

```
NewBox.prototype = Object.create(Box.prototype);
```

In that way, you express the same inheritance hierarchy without running your `Box` constructor that first time, avoiding any side effect that it might cause.

At last but not least, whenever you replace a function's prototype property is always recommended to restore the `constructor` property of this new prototype object, otherwise it will point to the wrong function.

In your example, since you replace the `NewBox.prototype` with a new instance of `Box`, the `NewBox.prototype.constructor` property will point to `Box`, (your instances are affected, e.g. `a.constructor === Box; // true`) instead of to `NewBox` as you would expect, we need to set it back, e.g.:

```
NewBox.prototype = someObject; // as any of the examples above
NewBox.prototype.constructor = NewBox;
```

You could abstract those details into a function, as I did in the `inherit` function above:

```
function inherits(child, parent) {
  var obj, Tmp = function () {};
  Tmp.prototype = parent.prototype;
  obj = new Tmp();
  child.prototype = obj;
  child.prototype.constructor = child;
}

//...

// instead of setting the `NewBox.prototype` manually
inherits(NewBox, Box); // "NewBox inherits from Box"

//...
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer! i learned a lot; i implemented it just as you said and it works perfectly. this is the sweet javascript workaround i was looking for.

Comment: That is calling *Box* as a function, not as a constructor, so you are just setting the id in the *NewBox* constructor, per Matt's answer.

Comment: @RobG, yeah, I said just *"call the Box constructor"* I didn't meant *"call Box as a constructor"*. Maybe *"call the Box constructor as a function"* or *"call the Box function with Function.prototype.apply"* should be clear enough, isn't it?

Comment: @tau, you're welcome!. If my answer fully satisfies your question, you can mark it as accepted...

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Matt Ball's answer is fine but this really explains what the problem is, that is, OP was instantiating a base object just to setup inheritance. Here's a plug for a post of mine about what it takes to setup inheritance properly http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/javascript-inheritance-done-right.html

Answer (score 1):

[Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682034/javascript-prototypal-inheritance-workaround/7682061#7682061) has the right idea. Instead try:

```
var Box = (function(){ 
    var numberOfBoxes = 0;
    function() {
        this.id = numberOfBoxes++;
    }
})();
```

Or in the case you want all your (different) classes to have unique ids:

```
var generateUniqueID = (function(){
    var runningCount = 0;
    return function (){
        return runningCount++;
    }
})();

var Box = function() {
    this.id = generateUniqueId();
};

var NewBox = function() {
    this.id = generateUniqueId();
    this.newThing = true;
};
```

Comment: yes, i figured that id have to delcare it for each instance. thanks!

Comment: @tau actually CMS has a solution for that if you don't want to have to declare it for each. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682034/javascript-prototypal-inheritance-workaround/7682111#7682111